# I cant check the solana version in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, solana, solana-cli

Im trying something out with the Solana CLI and I cant seem to get VS Code to recognise the `solana` command as valid on my system it just throws this error whenever I try to check the version:

````
file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included,   
verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ solana --version
+ ~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (solana:String) [], CommandNotFoundExcep  
   tion
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException```

Any help appreciated.
````

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the change to the `PATH` to include `solana` was not propagated if you just installed the Solana CLI.  Have you tried logging out or restarting your computer to see if it gets picked up?  A few things you can try:

- Change the command `solana.exe --version` to see if the `exe` is required
- Reinstall the CLI in a bash-compatible shell, such as Git Bash, and then use that shell in VS Code.  This is what I typically do.
- Install the CLI by hand so that the PATH is updated: https://docs.solana.com/cli/install-solana-cli-tools#windows-1

Otherwise, this may be a bug on the Solana side while installing the suite.

Answer (score 0):

That happened to me as well, what I did was to kill the terminal in VS Code and open a new terminal. That worked for me.